# Django filter many to many model's JSON field with the given

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have Movies and Participants model and it is like this,

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    something something
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(Participant)

class Participant(models.Model):
    something something 
    type = models.CharField(max_length=127, null=True, blank=True)
```

What I would like to do is, check the Participants **type** field with the given list and according to it list the Movies or not.

For example, I have `type_list=["Adults", "Children", "Senior"]` but Movie object has 2 Participant objects and one of them is `type="Adults"` and the other one is `type="Children"`

In example I would expect not to show that Movies since it doesn't have all the required Participants type.

What have I tried so far;

- `movie.participants.filter(type__in=["Adults", "Children", "Senior"])`

*however, this returns a two participants object*

- `movie.participants.filter(Q(type="Adults") | Q(type="Children") | Q(type="Senior")):`

*this one also returns the two participant object.*

*I also cant use the & operator.*

The only idea I left with is to check the count of the participants. Query returned two but I have three participant so I can't show this movie but the problem is in here list is variable that coming from front end. So my both query and if statement should be generic and I don't know how to do both and also I am %100 sure that there should be a best practice rather than this.

I would appreciate every tiny help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch all particiant's types using [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) with [`distinct`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) and compare returned value with provided type_list by iterating over provided list:

```
types_from_db = movie.participants.values_list("type", flat=True).distinct()

for movie_type in ["Adults", "Children", "Senior"]:
     if movie_type not in types_from_db:
         return False
return True
```

Comment: thank you this will do the trick and I will also make it generic.